# Kafka Rebalancing. Duplicate processing issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer worker application, that internally is launching `X` number of threads, each thread is spawning it's KafkaCosnumer. Cosnumers have the same `groupId` and are subscribed to the same topics. So, that each consumer gets it fair share of partitions.

The nature of the processing is that I cannot lose messages nor I can allow duplicates. The version of kafka I'm running is 0.10.2.1.

Here is the problem I am facing: consumer thread 1 starts consuming messages and on `poll()` gets a batch of messages. I also implement `ConsumerRebalanceListener`, so that every time message was successfully processed it gets added to the `offsets` map. (See code below.) So, once rebalancing is happening I could commit my offsets before my partitions get re-assigned to the other consumer. 
Sometimes, in order to process that batch, it takes longer than `max.poll.interval.ms`, this is where rebalancing occurs and partition is pulled from consumer 1 and assigned to consumer 2. Consumer 1 doesn't know that partition was revoked and keeps on processing messages, in the meantime consumer 2 picked up from the last offset (which was committed by the RebalanceListener) and processes same messages.

Is there a way to inform the consumer that he has partitions revoked so that he can stop processing messages in the loop, which were already assigned to the other consumer?

```
public class RebalanceListener<K, V> implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {

    private final KafkaConsumer<K, V> consumer;

    private static final ConcurrentMap<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> CURRENT_OFFSETS =
            Maps.newConcurrentMap();

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RebalanceListener.class);

    public RebalanceListener(KafkaConsumer<K, V> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public void addOffset(String topic, int partition, long offset) {
        LOGGER.debug("message=Adding offset to offsets map, topic={}, partition={}, offset={}",
                topic, partition, offset);
        CURRENT_OFFSETS.put(new TopicPartition(topic, partition),
                new OffsetAndMetadata(offset, "commit"));
    }

    public Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> getCurrentOffsets() {
        return CURRENT_OFFSETS;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        LOGGER.debug("message=following partitions have been revoked from consumer: [{}]",
                partitions.stream().map(
                        topicPartition -> topicPartition.topic() + ":" + topicPartition.partition())
                        .collect(joining(",")));
        LOGGER.debug("message=Comitting offsets for partititions [{}]",
                CURRENT_OFFSETS.keySet().stream().map(
                        topicPartition -> topicPartition.topic() + ":" + topicPartition.partition())
                        .collect(joining(",")));
        consumer.commitSync(CURRENT_OFFSETS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        LOGGER.debug("message=following partitions have been assigned to consumer: [{}]",
                partitions.stream().map(
                        topicPartition -> topicPartition.topic() + ":" + topicPartition.partition())
                        .collect(joining(",")));
    }

}
```

I think I could have a concurrent map of `consumerId -- TopicPartition` created inside of the `RebalanceListener` and then before processing every single message check if the current consumer is still associated with the record(each `ConsumerRecord` has `topic` and `partition` fields).
If not - break the cycle and make a next `poll()`.

This would be a viable solution if my worker app would be running in one single instance, even though having several KafkaConsumer threads spinning. But once I scale it up, I won't be able to stash offsets and consumer-topicPartition mapping in the static maps. That will have to be some kind of centralized storage, database or, let's say, Redis.

But then, before every time I process an item, I would have to ask if my record can be legitimately processed by current consumer thread. In case of scaled worker app, it will be a network call to the external storage, which would defeat the purpose of using kafka as it will slow down the processing. I might just opt in to perform offset commits after a single item was processed.

Comment: Kafka 1.0 was released last week. One of the features of 0.11 was supposedly exactly [once delivery](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/)

Comment: @StuartLC I know that `exactly once` semantics was introduced in 0.11, unfortunately, I cannot upgrade just yet to that version.

Comment: @StuartLC so, I read an article that you have linked above. I do not quite understand how consumer in 0.11 can handle my case. 
There's still a chance that the messages I have consumed take more than `max.poll.interval.ms` to get processed.  (I commit after an entire batch of msgs was processed). Messages will be in a process loop until all of them got processed. Sometime before that rebalancing is happening. Even though rebalancing occurred, my old consumer keeps on processing.
In the meantime, other consumer takes over that partition that was revoked. And messages will be processed twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement onPartitionsRevoked()

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html#onPartitionsRevoked(java.util.Collection)

> It is guaranteed that all consumer processes will invoke
>   onPartitionsRevoked prior to any process invoking
>   onPartitionsAssigned. So if offsets or other state is saved in the
>   onPartitionsRevoked call it is guaranteed to be saved by the time the
>   process taking over that partition has their onPartitionsAssigned
>   callback called to load the state.

Comment: I think you haven't read my question carefully. In the snippet that I have provided, I do have `onPartitionsRevoked()` implemented. 
The problem is not with the consumer that takes over the processing, but with the one that is considered dead but is still processing messages that were consumed during the last call to `poll()`

Comment: Yes but you are not storing offsets externally in your onPartitionsRevoked() implementation as described in the documentation. I don’t think you can commit offsets back to Kafka for partitions that have already been revoked. If you want to commit offsets to Kafka you need to do that as you finish processing and before the consumer gets its partitions revoked.

Comment: I have several consumer threads that are running within the same JVM. My rebalance listener has `addOffset()` method and it is adding offsets to the static concurrent map. It means that all of my consumer thread will be dealing with the same offset map.
Now, if we go back to the snippet that you have quoted above. It says that all consumer processes will invoke `onPartitionsRevoked()`. It means that all of my offsets will be persisted internally as they should have been.

Comment: I know that my implementation is flawed and if I scale my app I won't be running it on the same JVM anymore and I will have to go with the external storage.
But this is not the problem I am trying to solve. I do not know how to stop processing of the messages that were already consumed by the consumer that was proclaimed dead by the coordinator, but apparently is still alive (`max.poll.interval.ms` was exceeded) and still processing those messages in the loop.

Comment: Add a consumer.commitSync() into the code where you are processing the messages from the last poll(). That way if your poll() returns 50 messages and you commit after processing each message, it won't matter if the partition gets revoked after only 25 messages have been processed because you will always have committed offsets for the last successfully processed message. When the partition gets reassigned to another consumer it will continue from the right offset.

Comment: Initially I wanted to commit an offset only after a batch of messages was processed. That would give me a better performance as I would not have to commit after a single message was taken care of. But now I think committing after a single message was processed is the right thing to do.

Comment: Either that or save the offsets externally outside of Kafka. Otherwise you will get duplicates. Performance and duplicates are always a trade off with one another

Comment: What is the difference between storing to Kafka and storing to external storage? Here is case: consumer got 100 messages, 25 - processed, 26-th - takes too much time - coordinator calls revoke. I have to commit (commit to Kafka?) 25+1 (finish processing of the last message) messages and then close/restart consumer. Is it guaranteed that consumer-2 will start processing from 27-th?

Comment: I solved that using Zookeeper as the external store for offsets mapping and it works perfectly. After enabling of exactly once in Kafka 0.11 that should be done using Kafka itself...

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for ConsumerRebalanceListener says

> This callback will only execute in the user thread as part of the
>   poll(long) call whenever partition assignment changes.

So you don't have to be concerned about partition reassignment happening in the middle of processing the last batch of messages returned by poll().  It won't happen until you've finished processing all of those messages and call poll() again.

The javadoc also says:

> It is guaranteed that all consumer processes will invoke
>   onPartitionsRevoked prior to any process invoking
>   onPartitionsAssigned. So if offsets or other state is saved in the
>   onPartitionsRevoked call it is guaranteed to be saved by the time the
>   process taking over that partition has their onPartitionsAssigned
>   callback called to load the state.

Comment: This is normal behavior of kafka but he asks about the `max.poll.interval.ms` limit. When your work is takes longer than this limit your previously polled messages are polled again by new partition assignee. In this case same message is processed in the two worker at the same time.